# Reduce only up/down number size in NumberPicker

Tags: android, size, android-custom-view, numberpicker, android-number-picker

I want reduce size of up/down numbers (marked with arrow), keeping middle number size bigger.

[image: I want reduce size of up/down numbers, keeping middle number size bigger]

Comment: Anything you tried so far?

Comment: I've already extends NumberPicker class for changing it's font style & size. But size gets applied to all three numbers

Comment: Tried this but didn't work  '((EditText) picker.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));'

Answer (score 1):

you can use this library it will really help you

https://github.com/lantouzi/WheelView-Android

compile 'com.lantouzi.wheelview:library:1.0.1'